# Mosfet as switch Arduino 36V 1.5A

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am a bit confused with Vgs meaning. 
Vgs threshold should be <5V <40 mA because the Arduino cannot supply more.

In the [datasheet](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STP36NF06L/497-7522-5-ND/1039545) it says that the Vgs is +-18V and the Vgs threshold 1-2.5V. Does it mean that if the gate voltage is ~4V, that the maximal source voltage is then (4+18) 22V?

Answer (score 1):

You are well within Worst Case Limits for Vgs.
[image]

- It only means the higher your Vgs the lower the RdsOn

  - At some point between Vgs=1 to 2.5 Vds will start to conduct heavily.
    [image]
  - So with Vgs=5V you can expect RdsOn <= 0.05 Ohm

Comment: I think OP is also possibly confusing Vds with Vgs. It seems by the title he wants to switch 36V (within 60V Vds, but above 18V Vgsmax).

Comment: "At some point between Vgs=1 to 2.5 Vds will start to conduct heavily."  250 uA isn't quite "heavy"..

Answer (score 0):

If you put the load between the 36V source and the drain, the source will be 0V and a little more than 2.5 volts will turn the mosfet on.  If you are putting the load between the source and ground, drain to 36V, the voltage turn the device on will be much higher.  It would be easiest to put the load between the 36V source and the drain with the source to ground.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I never learned such basic knowledge in physic engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misreading your N-channel FET datasheet.
Let's start with what I think you are trying to do:

1. Drive a FET directly from the Arduino output pin (0V=OFF, 3.3V=ON)
2. Standoff a +36V supply when the FET is off
3. Connect some load between Drain and +36V that draws 1.5A (if it's reactive, like a motor you'll need a diode across the load of course)

If you look at the datasheet for the FET you selected, then look at Figure 3 "Output Characteristics". This is a pulse measurement and many confuse this. It's measured with the circuit at the end of the datasheet, Figure 14. This shows you that with a 4V (pulse) level on the Gate (ie the guaranteed high output voltage on an Arduino Pin) at 1.5A, then VDS can be low (perhaps only 0.5V). This means the device will dissipate about 800mW and the effective RDS is about 330mOhms. Looking now at Table 3, if you look at the VGs(th) you see that for any given device you may need 2.5V on the Gate just to begin turning the DS channel on. Nothing is specified between this 2.5V turnon and the 4V they show on Figure 3. So this device might saturate with the Arduino drive voltage at your load, but it might not.
Now depending on whether you are using a 3.3V or 5V Arduino, the situation will change radically.

Now look at this datasheet: http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/rtq020n05.pdf

This is a 45V "Logic Level" N-Channel FET, and has a very much more sensitive Gate turnon voltage. Look at Fig 5 "Typical Output Characteristics(1)".
Notice on this graph that a 4V VGS with 1.5A load VDS will be around 0.22V. So this gives about 330mW dissipation or effectively 150mOhms RDS.

Notice also that this device has a maximum VGS(th) of only 1.5V so begins to turn on much earlier.

So what to do for your application, with a 5V Arduino I'd suggest that you provide an external Pin pullup of 470 Ohms (about 10mA load when pin=low) to ensure you get the full 5V drive. It might work out OK with your original device, but I'd suggest you select a 'Logic Level' sensitive Gate device as shown above. The nice thing about FET's is that you can parallel them and they share current (though there will be ID differences of course) very well.

If you are using a 3.3V Arduino then you definitely need a 'Logic Level' device and will have to carefully select your FET device.